Elementor "Items Per Page" not working on "Search Results" page's "Loop Grid"
I've created a "Search Results" page template with a "Loop Grid" set to "Current Query" and the "Items Per Page" setting set to 20.
When testing a search, instead of limiting the results to 20, it just shows all of them on the page, which are in the hundreds, causing the page to take ages to load. None of the pagination settings work either.
I tested changing the Query to "Posts" or any of the other custom post types and it does follow the "Items Per Page" limit of 20 with working pagination. So it only doesn't work if it's set to "Current Query."
Has anyone else come across this issue, and if so, come up with a solution?
